# Difference between 2 list

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.6

I'm having the following problem when outputting the items that are in a list that are not in second list.

Here is the code:

```
def getInitialList(): # Define initial list with the use of requests and BS, will return a set

    getInHtml = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1")
    parseInHtml = BeautifulSoup(getInHtml.content, "html.parser")

    processInHtml = parseInHtml.find_all("div", class_="inner-article")

    firstList = []

    for items in processInHtml:
        firstList.append(items)

    return firstList

def getSecList(): #Define second list with the use of requests and BS, will return a set
    getHtml = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1")
    parseHtml = BeautifulSoup(getHtml.content, "html.parser")

    processHtml = parseHtml.find_all("div", class_="inner-article")

    secList = []

    for items in processHtml:
        secList.append(items)

    return secList

def catch_new_item():

    initList = getInitialList()

    while True:
        if initList == getSecList():
            print("No new items")
        else:
            print("New items found")
            break
    secList = getSecList()
    return set(secList) - set(initList)
```

This last function (catch_new_items()), should return what is in the secList thats not in the initList, but when I run it it returns an empty set.

The address 127.0.0.1 its a local web server that im running to determine the difference between this 2 items. All i do is edit the html and add one more element to it.

Let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified code in this way, to debug it:

```
def getInitialList(): # Define initial list with the use of requests and BS, will return a set

    firstList = ['1', '2', '3']
    return firstList

def getSecList(): #Define second list with the use of requests and BS, will return a set

    secList = ['a', 'b', '3', '1']
    return secList

def catch_new_item():

    initList = getInitialList()
    while True:
        if initList == getSecList():
            print("No new items")
        else:
            print("New items found")
        break
    secList = getSecList()
    return set(secList) - set(initList)

print(catch_new_item())
```

and it returns:

```
New items found
{'a'}
```

So logic of items detection is good.

1. Did you try just to print out your lists from getInitialList() and
   getSecList() functions to see, whether they are empty?
2. Do lists really contain different items? (if they are not empty, see
   p. 1)

Comment: This lists parse the same html page , with the difference that the secondList will keep getting the html elements until it finds 1 difference or more, then the catch function should output the items thats in secList and thats not in initList.